# How to pass parameter to unnamed route: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a route:

**router.js**:

```
       {
            path: "/books/new/:title",
            name: "new_book",
            component: () => 
import('./components/user/NewBookView.vue')
        }
```

to which I try to push via router:

**CreateBook.vue**:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "new_book",
    params: {
         title: this.bookJson.data.title,
         book: this.bookJson.data
    }
});
```

However I get a

```
Error in nextTick: "TypeError: 
Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"
```

error.

I need the `bookJson` to be passed as param to my `NewBookView.vue` component:

**NewBookView.vue**:

```
...
        data:  function()  {
            return {
                book: JSON
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.book = 
this.$route.params.book;
        }
...
```

I tried to do

```
this.$router.push({
    path: "/books/new/" + 
this.booksJson.data.title,
    params: {
         book: this.bookJson.data
    }
});
```

but the `book` parameter seems to be `undefined`.

So it seems that I can't pass the parameter unless the route is named, but if it's named I can't push to it either.

**EDIT**: I tried to change it to this, but still get the `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"` error:

**router.js**:

```
{
    path: "/books/new/:title",
    name: "new_book",
    component: () => import('./components/user/NewBookView.vue'),
    props: route => ({
        // set component property book to the route.params.book value
        book: route.params.book,
        ...route.params
    })
}
```

**CreateBook.vue**:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "new_book",
    params: {
         title: this.bookJson.data.title,
         book: this.bookJson.data
    }
});
})
```

**NewBookView.vue**:

```
export default {
    props:  {
        book: JSON
    },
    created() {
        this.props.book = this.$route.params.book;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [props function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode)

set your router like this:

```js
{
    path: "/books/new/:title",
    name: "book",
    component: () => import("../pages/Book.vue"),
    props: route => ({
        // set component property book to the route.params.book value
        book: route.params.book,
        ...route.params
    })
}
```

and instead of using `data`, use `props` on your component:

```js
export default {
  name: "home",
  props: {
    title: String, 
    book: Object
  }
};
```

and push to your route like this:

```js
this.$router.push({
    name: "book",
    params: {
        title: "Foo Bar",
        book: {
            id: 1,
            title: "Foo Bar",
            author: "John Doe"
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-demo-3cfqs?file=/pages/Home.vue

Comment: I tried changing my code to props, but still get the same error (see EDIT)

Comment: `JSON` is not a valid props type, use `Object` instead. Check available types [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks)

Comment: And you dont need to set props value in created.

Comment: Thank you, got it working! Do you know why is it this way? Why Vue decided not to allow non-named routes to have parameters? Why a prop can't be `JSON`?

Comment: You still can pass parameters to unnamed route, but not from `params`, you need to concat the path as a string directly like `this.$router.push(\`/books/new/${title}\`)`. Props can't be JSON because technically there's no "JSON" type in javascript, Object is as close as it can get to a JSON.

Comment: Right. But why I can't pass non-URL-query params? The parameters that are in the body, rather than in the query that is in the address line?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's just because of how Vue design their router, as mentioned in [this page](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation), "params are ignored if a path is provided", which means you can only pass parameter as the path, unlike named route